# szimek signature-pad saving image to file

Tags: javascript, html

I use this code to copy signature pad image to a hidden field. Everything works great except chrome and safari browsers to not work.

Form fields:

```
<form id="sigform" action="myscript.php" method="post">
   <input id="sigdataid" type="hidden" name="sigdata" value=""/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" > 
</form>
```

Code in app.js:

```
function myFunctionsub() {
    if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
        alert("Please provide a signature first.");
    } else {
        var image = signaturePad.toDataURL();
        document.getElementById("sigdataid").value = image;
        document.getElementById("sigform").submit();
     }
}
```

The hidden field does receive image data on IE and Firefox and data is present after submitting. However, Chrome and Safari do not receive the data and is not present when the form is posted.

I have done extensive research and can not find any information on Chrome compatibility on either the `var image = signaturePad.toDataURL();` or  `document.getElementById("sigdataid").value = image;` javascript code.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: where does `signaturePad` come from?

Comment: I downloaded from https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad

Comment: Can you post  jsfiddle or otherwise complete example demonstrating this behavior? I took parts of your HTML and JS and added them to the jsfiddle linked from the signature_pad documentation (https://jsfiddle.net/szimek/d6a78gwq/) and it looks like the hidden element does have the correct value (in Safari).

Comment: I finally figured this out. the routine was all ok.  I had my hosting company downgrade from PHP 7 to PHP 5. That did the trick. This routine now works every time on all browsers